# Java- The meaning of <T extends Comparable<T>>?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

The full context being:

```
public class RClass<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Would I be right in saying that the statement in the title means that the arguments plugged into the method must either be an object of a class which implements Comparable OR one of its derived classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Note, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` (I think you can do that there), would be preferable, as you might want `T` to be more precise than its implementation of `Comparable`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Can you give an example of why this be necessary?  Say i have my List data structure that only works with comparable types. The way I would specify this is public class MyList<T extends Comparable<T>>. I think that would state and enforce that my data structure only works with comparable types, How would your phrasing make a difference?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline You might want a natural ordering by *exactly* the type you are dealing with, because polymorphic less than is *funky*

Comment: @committedandroider `java.sql.Timestamp` (which is `Comparable<Date>`). This example is a bit "funky", but if you're dealing with SQL, as many people have to, then it is what you've got.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This means that the type parameter must support comparison with other instances of its own type, via the Comparable interface.

An example of such a class is provided in the Oracle tutorial [Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). Note the similar pattern to `T extends Comparable<T>` in the excerpt below:

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {
   ...
   public int compareTo(Name n) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Why not just have Name implements Comparable? Why need to specify the class name again?

Comment: @committedandroider because Comparable is a generic interface you need to specify the type

Comment: This is a good answer. But it's interesting in bounded generic types, Java doesn't differentiate between interface implementation and class inheritance - `<T implements Comparable<T>>` is not legal.

Comment: Why is extends allowed here if `Comparable` is an interface? Shouldn't it be `implements`? You can't extend an interface.

Comment: @piepi - Because it's useful, and because the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) says so. Using a single keyword to indicate subtyping in generic type parameters allows cases like `T extends U`, that work whether U is a class type or interface type. This differs from class declarations, in which you're subtyping known (though possibly parameterized) types.

Answer (score 22):

**Java- The meaning of** `<T extends Comparable<T>>`**?**

a) `Comparable <T>` 
is a generic interface (remember it's an "interface" i.e not a "class")

b) `extends` means inheritance from a class or an interface.

From above-said point#a, it is an interface..(Remember it is an inheritance from an "interface"  i.e not from a "class")

c)From above-said both points #a & #b,

here "one interface" extends "another interface".

There should be an interface defined for this class..
just  an example here is

```
interface MinMax<T extends Comparable<T>> { 
    T min(); 
    T max(); 
}
```

d) now your class i.e `public class RClass {}` SHOULD

1# EITHER "implement" this "generic interface" `Comparable<T>` ..!!!

ex: `public class RClass<T> implements Comparable<T>`

2# OR create an interface and extend to this "generic interface" `Comparable<T>`
   ex:

```
interface MinMax<T extends Comparable<T>> { 
   T min(); 
   T max(); 
} 
class RClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MinMax<T> {
    .....
    .....
}
```

Here,
   Pay special attention to the way that the type parameter T is declared by RClass and
   then passed to `MinMax`. Because `MinMax` requires a type that implements `Comparable`,
   the implementing class (RClass in this case) must specify the same bound. Furthermore,
   once this bound has been established, there is no need to specify it again in the implements clause.

Comment: In the question, it's been asked that `public **class** RClass<T extends Comparable<T>>`. It's a class and not an interface. So please comment on what will be the meaning if it's a class.

Comment: great answer. question: why `class A<T extends Comparable<T>>` but not `class A<T implements Comparable<T>>`? For example, `A` can be `A<Integer>`. Here `Integer` is `T` and `Integer` class `implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

Answer (score 9):

Somewhere in that class, the programmer needs to write something like

```
if(t.compareTo(othert) < 0) {
    ...
}
```

For that to work, the type T must have a compareTo-method which compares it to another object of type T. Extending Comparable guarantees the existence of such a method, among other things.

Answer (score 4):

It means that you can only create an instance of `RClass` with a type which quite literally extends `Comparable<T>`. Thus,

```
RClass<Integer> a;
```

is acceptable, since `Integer` extends `Comparable<Integer>`, while

```
RClass<Object> b;
```

is not, since `Object` is not a class which extends comparable at all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and bear in mind that objects of classes derived from `Comparable` **ARE** `Comparable` objects. Inheritance is a `is-a` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, the generic type T must be comparable in order to compareTo. otherwise you cannot do T.compareTo.
In Item 28 Effective java, it suggests: `"always use Comparable<? super T> in preference to Comparable<T>. <T extends Comparable<? super T>>"`

Answer (score 1):

==>guhanvj,   `<T extends Comparable<T>>` means that `<T>` is having upper bound of `Comparable<T>` objects. So `<T>` can have types of Byte, Character, Double, Float, Long, Short, String, and Integer classes which all implements  `Comparable<T>` interface for natural ordering.