# How to deal with generic bounds migrating from Java to Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

My goal is to have the interface methods accept the class type of the implementation. Here's the code I have written so far:

```
internal interface Diff<Diff> {   //in Java I was using <? extends Diff>
    fun lessThan(other: Diff): Boolean
}

private class ADiff(private val value: Int) : Diff<ADiff> {

    override fun lessThan(other: ADiff): Boolean {
        return value < other.value
    }

}

//B can now accept even int types which is not desired
private class BDiff(private val value: Int) : Diff<Int> {

    override fun lessThan(other: Int): Boolean {
        return value < other
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this "worked" in Java was because `<T extends Diff>` uses the [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `Diff`. Don't do this!

---

The closest you can get is to use a recursive type bound:

```
interface Diff<T : Diff<T>> {
    fun lessThan(other: T): Boolean
}
```

The problem is, you can substitute any other subtype of `Diff`.

However, when *using* the `Diff`, use the generic type constraint `T : Diff<T>`:

```
fun <T : Diff<T>> diffUser(diff1: T, diff2: T) {
    println(diff1.lessThan(diff2))
}
```

and any `Diff` that doesn't implement `Diff<SameType>` will not be accepted.

Example:

```
class CDiff(private val value: Int) : Diff<DDiff> { // <-- Wrong type!
    override fun lessThan(other: DDiff) = value < other.value
}

class DDiff(val value: Int) : Diff<DDiff> {
    override fun lessThan(other: DDiff) = value < other.value
}

fun test() {
    diffUser(CDiff(3), CDiff(4)) // <-- Doesn't compile due to the generic constraint
    diffUser(DDiff(3), DDiff(4))
}
```

[This same approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537500/java-the-meaning-of-t-extends-comparablet) is used by the `Comparable` class.

---

Although this works, what you *really* want is a "self type" [and this is not supported, although it was on the roadmap at some point](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371). I believe JetBrains denied the request for this, though I cannot find the bug report.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7355094/7366707) details a workaround in Java using [the CRT pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), though it is not necessarily type safe.