# How to resolve `Raw use of parameterized class 'Comparable'` warning?

Tags: java, oop, generics, wildcard, raw-types

Got to implement the method below for an assignment which it's subject is "WildCards", but don't know where to use wildcards in order to resolve the warning.

```
static <T extends Comparable> T findMax(T ... items)
{
    T max = items[0];
    for (T item : items)
        if (item.compareTo(max) > 0)
            max = item;
    return max;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537500/java-the-meaning-of-t-extends-comparablet) on why you have to change `<T extends Comparable>` to `<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Comment: A comment on the code: since arrays are covariant, while generics are invariant, using a generic varargs parameter may set you up for trouble.

Comment: Should be safe, as the array is only ever queried, not modified though?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Comparable` is a generic interface, so to use it safely you must always specify the generic type to use. In your case, something like:

```java
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

is likely what you're looking for. Otherwise, the compiler is unable to help you verify that the types are actually compatible in all scenarii.

Comment: Thank you that solved the warning. But not every time T is going to be compared with its own type. How can I handle that (It's type is neither its super nor its child) ? . When I put `?` instead of `T` in `Comparable<T>` I get the error `Required type: 'capture of ?' , Provided : 'T' `

Comment: I don't think there will be any practical case where comparing two objects of completely unrelated types will be necessary or useful. It just seems like poor design. You'd use `<Object>`, but please never do that :p

Comment: How would you even onctruct such a call? Even if your type `T` is a  `Comparable<Object>`, how could you pass anything other than `T` as a method parameter?

Comment: Like this: https://gist.github.com/Dicee/e54be66700bf4534d49d2c24b564e62a

Comment: Well unfortunately only for the sake of learning T was comparable only with type which was neither its child nor its parent :)

Comment: or even better, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`